# Is it possible to place a HTTP Post and Get request for a specific button click? [Node.js, Express[

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, express, get

I have a main login page where in my HTML page, where I have added a script.

```
<script>
                var username, password;

                function doSomething() {
                    username = $('#username').val();
                    password = $('#password').val();
                    $.post('/login', {
                        user: username,
                        password: password
                    });
                    //$.get('/database');
                }
            </script>
```

And my POST request in my .js file for the index page looks like this:

```
app.post('/login', function (req, res) {
        var username = req.body.user;
        var password = req.body.password;

        console.log("Username: " + username + ", password: " + password);
        if (username === 'john' && password === 'johnspassword') {
            res.redirect('/database');
        } else {
            //            res.send('Bad user/pass');
        }
        res.redirect('/database');
    });
```

While I have another .js file where I implemented a GET request on

```
 app.get('/database', function (req, res) {

     res.render('database');
});
```

However when I click the button to run the function `doSomething()`, it only shows in the console.log the username and password I am entering but it is not redirecting to the new location.

When I separately go to localhost/database, I am able to render my database HTML/HANDLEBARS. How would I go about reaching that page from the POST

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do your redirection on the client-side.

After your success ajax:

```
$.ajax({
   url : '/login',
   type : 'POST',
   data : {
     user: username,
     password: password
   },
   success : function(data){
      window.location.replace(data);
   }
});
```

And change the response on server-side

```
app.post('/login', function (req, res) {
    var username = req.body.user;
    var password = req.body.password;

    console.log("Username: " + username + ", password: " + password);
    if (username === 'john' && password === 'johnspassword') {
        res.status(200).send('/database');
    } else {
        //            res.send('Bad user/pass');
    }
    res.status(200).send('/database');
});
```

Comment: Antoine, thanks a lot! It worked! But could you explain why I am using window.location.replace(data)? Isn't the data passed in supposed to be a new url or atleast according to the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace.

Comment: Actually, data is an url. Your server send that: res.status(200).send('/database'); So, in the success ajax, data = '/database'.